# Set p:inputText value from bean in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page containing this form :

```
<h:form id="signupForm">
    <p>
        <p:inputText size="40" placeholder="Name" style="font-family: 'Raleway', serif;" binding="#{name}"></p:inputText><br/><br/>
        <p:inputText size="40" placeholder="Username" style="font-family: 'Raleway', serif;" value="#{fromHomeToSignUp.email}"></p:inputText><br/><br/>
        <p:password size="20" placeholder="Password" style="font-family: 'Raleway', serif;" value="#{fromHomeToSignUp.password}"></p:password>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <p:commandButton update="signupForm" value="Sign up now" style="background:#FFCB4C" action="#{fromHomeToSignUp.goToSignUp()}"></p:commandButton>
    </p>
</h:form>
```

I pass my values to a bean called `fromHomeToSignUp`. 
This bean redirects myself to signup page.xhtml but I need to set some `<p:inputText>` values inside it with values just passed to that bean .

How can I do it?

Comment: Aren't those values set to the bean - `#{fromHomeToSignUp.email}`, `#{fromHomeToSignUp.password}`?

Comment: What your method `#{fromHomeToSignUp.goToSignUp()}` ,do ? post your code please.